# Transitividade verbal:

Tags: transitividade-verbal

Na frase
• Tudo se clareou para mim.
o sintagma "para mim" não esta previsto nos dicionários como objeto indireto, ja que definem o verbo clarear nesse sentido como VTD ou VI.
Essa oração então é possível de acordo com a norma padrão ou existe apenas no coloquialismo?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Os dicionários fornecem apenas informação sobre a estrutura argumental do predicado, i.e., constituintes do predicado que sejam obrigatórios para completar o significado do mesmo. Para *clarear*, temos predicados com as duas estruturas que encontraste no dicionário:

> O azul da noite é **clareado** por focos de neve que caem devagarinho. *(transitivo direto)*
>   O mar estava um pouco agitado e um vento forte batia as cristas das ondas, enquanto a lua ia desaparecendo no céu que **clareava**. *(intransitivo)*

Verbos com este padrão (A cleareou B /  B clareou) dizem-se de *verbos de alternância*. A versão intransitiva faz-se geralmente acompanhar do clítico *se* (dito anticausativo), mas nem sempre.

Não me parece que *para mim* complemente o significado de *clarear* nas frase *Tudo se clareou para mim* / *Tudo se me cleareou*. *Tudo se clareou* é uma frase perfeitamente gramatical e *clarear* tem o mesmo significado. *Para mim* é assim um adjunto (adverbial), não um complemento (relativo).

Comment: Também cheguei a esse raciocínio antes de formular minha dúvida. A dificuldade que encontrei pra classificar o então suposto adjunto adverbial "para mim" diluiu minhas certesas. Mas se encararmos a prep. "para" denotando direção física, embora soe estranho, faz sentido chamala de adj. Adv. de lugar. Teria o mesmo significado de "em mim".

Comment: @M.MELO De lugar certamente não é. Diria que é um dativo de interesse, porque nomeia o beneficiário do clareamento.

Comment: @M.MELO e Artefacto, A Gramática do Português da Gulbenkian (cap. 28) concorda. Diz, a propósito de verbos diferentes (e.g. "construiu uma casa para os pais"/"... aos pais"), que estes *para X/a X* desempenham o papel temático de beneficiário (e são semanticamente equivalentes). Mas diz que, baseado em critérios sintáticos *para X* é em rigor um adjunto advebial.